# How to fix ERROR 1064 (42000) syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I change my root password using `update user set authentication_string=password("!QAZxsw2") where user="root";` this syntax but the error `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("!QAZxsw2") where user="root"' at line 1` keeps pop up. I don't know why please help!

I've google this question and most of the articles tell me to use `update user set authentication_string=password("!QAZxsw2")where user ="root";` this syntax to change my root password. I can't find where did I make it wrong. By the way, I have also tried this code `set password for root@localhost = password('!QAZxsw2');` However, still get the same result.

```sql
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password("!QAZxsw2") where user="root";
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("!QAZxsw2") where user="root"' at line 1
```

Comment: Please specify your mysql version

Comment: @Ponni my mysql version is 8.0.16

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier

mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("!QAZxsw2") where User='root';

MySQL 5.7.6 and newer

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD("!QAZxsw2");

OR Try with the below command, it works for me in mysql8:

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'='!QAZxsw2';

Comment: ```ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD("!QAZxsw2")' at line 1``` Same error after using lastest version syntax.

Comment: SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'='!QAZxsw2'; Please try with it. It works for me in mysql8.

Comment: I tried and then it pop out this ```ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table``` and then I use ```SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;``` surprisingly, it pop out user "root". Why is it?

Comment: @Jessie were you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use string value in single quotes, for example,

```
update user set authentication_string=password('!QAZxsw2') where user='root';
```

see link - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-change-user-password/

For MySQL version 5.7.6 or greater use command

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD("!QAZxsw2");
```

Comment: After I changed it to single quotes, I still get the  same error!

Comment: SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD("newpass");  please try with it